# Angular JS ng-model is becoming null on selecting from drop down list

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am a novice in angular js. I am creating some application where i am selecting a value from drop down list and the selected value is associated with ng-model. But i see that the ng-model is actually becoming null instead of gettting a value.
My whole code is:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <h2>Select one Item from left and one Item from right</h2>
        <select ng-model="leftmodel"
                ng-change="ChangeOptions()"
                ng-options="option as option.value disable
  when option.disabled for option in left">
        </select>

        <select ng-model="rightmodel"
                ng-change="ChangeOptions()"
                ng-options="option as option.value disable when option.disabled for option in right">

        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    var module = angular.module("app", []);
    module.controller("MyCtrl",
            function($scope) {
                $scope.left = [{
                    "name": "apple",
                    "value": "Nice Apple",
                    "disabled": false
                }, {
                    "name": "orange",
                    "value": "Yellow Orange",
                    "disabled": true
                }, {
                    "name": "berry",
                    "value": "Blue Berry",
                    "disabled": false
                }];

                $scope.right = [{
                    "name": "apple",
                    "value": "Nice Apple",
                    "disabled": true
                }, {
                    "name": "orange",
                    "value": "Yellow Orange",
                    "disabled": false
                }, {
                    "name": "berry",
                    "value": "Blue Berry",
                    "disabled": false
                }];

                $scope.leftmodel = $scope.left[0];
                $scope.rightmodel = $scope.right[1];
                $scope.ChangeOptions = function() {
                    var size = $scope.left.length;
                    console.log(size);
                    console.log($scope.leftmodel);
                    console.log($scope.rightmodel);
                    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                        if ($scope.left[i].name === $scope.rightmodel.name) {
                            $scope.right[i].disabled = true;
                        } else {
                            $scope.right[i].disabled = false;
                        }
                    }

                    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                        if ($scope.right[i].name === $scope.leftmodel.name) {
                            $scope.left[i].disabled = true;
                        } else {
                            $scope.left[i].disabled = false;
                        }
                    }
                };

            }
    );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I also have a [Codpen](https://codepen.io/johirbuet/pen/RKWdBR)
In console i get the following errors:

> 3 Object {   $$hashKey: "object:5",   disabled: false,   name:
>   "berry",   value: "Blue Berry" } Object {   $$hashKey: "object:7",
>   disabled: false,   name: "orange",   value: "Yellow Orange" } 3 null
>   Object {   $$hashKey: "object:7",   disabled: true,   name: "orange", 
>   value: "Yellow Orange" } "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of
>   null
>       at ChildScope.$scope.ChangeOptions (pen.js:87:58)
>       at fn (eval at compile (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:15156:15),
>   :4:159)
>       at ChildScope.$eval (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:17972:28)
>       at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:25711:13
>       at Object. (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:28536:9)
>       at forEach (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:357:20)
>       at Object.$$writeModelToScope (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:28534:5)
>       at writeToModelIfNeeded (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:28527:14)
>       at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:28521:9
>       at validationDone (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:28446:9)"
>   3 null null "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null
>       at ChildScope.$scope.ChangeOptions (pen.js:79:58)
>       at fn (eval at compile (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:15156:15),
>   :4:159)
>       at ChildScope.$eval (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:17972:28)
>       at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:25711:13
>       at Object. (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:28536:9)
>       at forEach (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:357:20)
>       at Object.$$writeModelToScope (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:28534:5)
>       at writeToModelIfNeeded (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:28527:14)
>       at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:28521:9
>       at validationDone (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:28446:9)"
>   Do anyone have any idea why this is happening. What i want to do is select a value from left drop down menu and dont allowing the user to select the same value from other drop down list. That meansif a user selects some value from left select box he will not be able to select that from right select box and vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
$scope.ChangeOptions = function() {

      var lsize = $scope.left.length;
      var rsize = $scope.left.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < lsize; i++) {

        console.log($scope.left[i]);
        if ($scope.left[i].name === $scope.rightmodel.name) {
          $scope.left[i].disabled = true;
        } else {
          $scope.left[i].disabled = false;
        }
      }

      for (var i = 0; i < rsize; i++) {
        if ($scope.right[i].name === $scope.leftmodel.name) {
          $scope.right[i].disabled = true;
        } else {
          $scope.right[i].disabled = false;
        }
      }
    };
```

Code Pen : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dNYLpN

Comment: Still I am not getting what is the problem in my code and what magical change in your code makes it work

Comment: @MdJohirulIslam your conditionals are backwards.  In the original code, you are disabling the right side if the left matches, and visa versa.  this causes the opposite dropdown to suddenly be invalid, causing it to change, causing another digest cycle, which now causes the first dropdown to be set to an invalid value as well.  This code changes the left side if the left matches, and the right side if the right matches, which works.

Comment: @Claies Thanks,Well explained , here is how you can see this happening and viewing when the model becomes null due to this .https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YNybed